# Efficient way to slice and subset data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I need to repeatedly slice a large `dataframe` (based on row indices) and subset it based on values from one column. The dimension of my `DF` is >1E8 rows and it looks like those two steps were the most time consuming. I am wondering if there are any ways to reduce computing time?

I tried to use `data.table`, but it took some time to `setkey`, so I am not sure if that would be a better choice.

```
library(profvis)
profvis({

    library(dplyr)
    set.seed(1234)

    # create testing df
    n=1e8
    raw_data <- data.frame(label=sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), n, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(n))

    # data slice indices
    slide_begin=3000000
    slide_end=9000000

    # subset df
    raw_data_sub <- raw_data[slide_begin:slide_end,]
    raw_data_sub_A <-raw_data_sub[which(raw_data_sub$label=="A"), ]
    raw_data_sub_NA <-raw_data_sub[is.na(raw_data_sub$label), ]


})
```

Comment: by "subset it based on values from one column" you mean `raw_data_sub$label=="A"`

Comment: @PoGibas, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code to compare the data frame subset approach in base R, `dplyr`, and `data.table`. The result shows that `data.table` is the fastest.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1234)

# create testing df
n <- 1e8
raw_data <- data.frame(label=sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), n, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(n))

# data slice indices
slide_begin <- 3000000
slide_end <- 9000000

# Convert raw_data to a data.table
raw_data_dt <- as.data.table(raw_data)

# Microbenchmark
microbenchmark(m1 = {raw_data_sub <- raw_data[slide_begin:slide_end,]
                     raw_data_sub_A <-raw_data_sub[which(raw_data_sub$label %in% "A"), ]
                     raw_data_sub_NA <-raw_data_sub[is.na(raw_data_sub$label), ]},
               m2 = {raw_data_sub_tbl <- raw_data %>% slice(slide_begin:slide_end)
                     raw_data_sub_A_tbl <- raw_data_sub_tbl %>% filter(label %in% "A")
                     raw_data_sub_NA_tbl <- raw_data_sub_tbl %>% filter(is.na(label))},
               m3 = {raw_data_sub_dt <- raw_data_dt[slide_begin:slide_end, ]
                     raw_data_sub_A_dt <- raw_data_sub_dt[label %in% "A", ]
                     raw_data_sub_NA_dt <-  raw_data_sub_dt[is.na(label), ]})
```

**Result**

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   m1 978.6438 1122.0304 1222.5156 1190.4979 1292.8300 1880.6840   100
   m2 392.9376  397.2833  466.8690  409.5631  517.5746 1010.1591   100
   m3 221.8958  225.9560  281.8417  231.0487  281.1333  678.4515   100
```

Comment: thanks for showing the comparison. So it looks like not always to `setkey` in `data.table`?

Comment: In this case, I used the same syntax as base R, but you may want to test on your real world data.